# how to save or prevent my background service from the force stop or clear task from user

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, service

Hello friends i am creating one android app App lock application in which user can lock the application for that i am using one background service which run in background always. My service is run fine in all device but in some new device like OPPO,Redme Mi and Lenovo Mobile there is one advace feature like user can clean all the running task from the cleaner and because of this advance features when user clean all the task my service also stop and app lock will not work so user need to go in application and manual start the service is there any solution to protect my service from this.
one of app lock have this kind of solution 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock
This app service is start after the clean task i also want to do same for my application i tried many solution but not getting any result i my service code is as below

```
public class MyAppLockService extends Service {
public static int BuildV = 0;
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 11259186;
private static boolean flag;
public static boolean isLauncher;
public static boolean isRunning;
public static ArrayList<String> locked_list;
public static String pack;
public static Thread th;
String currentHomePackage;
private boolean isRefreshedList;
boolean mAllowDestroy;
BroadcastReceiver mReciever;
private boolean mShowNotification;
UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager;
ActivityManager manager;
PowerManager pmanager;
SharedPreferences prefs;
public boolean run;
Timer f6t;
TimerTask tt;

class C02221 extends BroadcastReceiver {
    C02221() {
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Utils.ACTION_UPDATE)) {
            MyAppLockService.this.refreshList();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Utils.ACTION_STOP_SELF)) {
            MyAppLockService.this.doStopSelf();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Utils.ACTION_REMOVE_APP)) {
            MyAppLockService.this.removeAppFromLockedList(intent
                    .getStringExtra("packName"));
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")

class C02232 extends TimerTask {
    C02232() {
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void run() {
        if (Utils.isScreenOn(MyAppLockService.this.pmanager)) {
            MyAppLockService.this.isRefreshedList = false;
            String current = "";
            try {
                current = Utils.getProcess(
                        MyAppLockService.this.mUsageStatsManager,
                        MyAppLockService.this.getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                current = "";
            }
            if (current != null) {
                if (MyAppLockService.flag
                        && current
                                .equals(MyAppLockService.this.currentHomePackage)) {
                    if (MyAppLockService.this.prefs.getBoolean(
                            "immediately", true)) {
                        MyAppLockService.locked_list = new DBHelper(
                                MyAppLockService.this
                                        .getApplicationContext())
                                .getApsHasStateTrue();
                    }
                    MyAppLockService.flag = false;
                }
                if (!current
                        .equals(MyAppLockService.this.currentHomePackage)
                        && MyAppLockService.locked_list.contains(current)) {
                    Intent it;
                    if (MyAppLockService.BuildV >= 23) {
                        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        UsageEvents usageEvents = MyAppLockService.this.mUsageStatsManager
                                .queryEvents(endTime - 10000, endTime);
                        Event event = new Event();
                        while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
                            usageEvents.getNextEvent(event);
                        }
                        if (current.equals(event.getPackageName())
                                && event.getEventType() == 1) {
                            MyAppLockService.pack = current;
                            if (MyAppLockService.this.prefs.getBoolean(
                                    "isPattern", false)) {
                                MyAppLockService.this
                                        .confirmPattern(current);
                            } else {
                                it = new Intent(
                                        MyAppLockService.this
                                                .getApplicationContext(),
                                        AppLockActivity.class);
                                it.setFlags(DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY);
                                MyAppLockService.this
                                        .getApplicationContext()
                                        .startActivity(it);
                            }
                            MyAppLockService.flag = true;
                            return;
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    MyAppLockService.pack = current;
                    if (MyAppLockService.this.prefs.getBoolean("isPattern",
                            false)) {
                        MyAppLockService.this.confirmPattern(current);
                    } else {
                        it = new Intent(
                                MyAppLockService.this
                                        .getApplicationContext(),
                                AppLockActivity.class);
                        it.setFlags(DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY);
                        MyAppLockService.this.getApplicationContext()
                                .startActivity(it);
                    }
                    MyAppLockService.flag = true;
                }
            }
        } else if (!MyAppLockService.this.isRefreshedList) {
            MyAppLockService.this.refreshList();
        }
    }
}

public MyAppLockService() {
    this.run = true;
}

static {
    BuildV = VERSION.SDK_INT;
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void onCreate() {




    this.prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    this.manager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService("activity");
    this.pmanager = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService("power");
    if (BuildV >= 21) {
        this.mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService("usagestats");
    }
    startNotification();
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
    this.currentHomePackage = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent,
            Cast.MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH).activityInfo.packageName;
    this.mReciever = new C02221();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Utils.ACTION_UPDATE);
    filter.addAction(Utils.ACTION_STOP_SELF);
    filter.addAction(Utils.ACTION_REMOVE_APP);
    registerReceiver(this.mReciever, filter);
    refreshList();
    this.tt = new C02232();
    this.f6t = new Timer();
    this.f6t.schedule(this.tt, 500, 500);
    super.onCreate();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent12 = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyAppLockService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getBaseContext(), 0, intent12, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),5, pintent);
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY, startId);

}

public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        this.f6t.cancel();
        this.tt.cancel();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.android.techtrainner");
        intent1.putExtra("yourvalue", "torestore");
        sendBroadcast(intent1);


}



public void refreshList() {
    locked_list = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext())
            .getApsHasStateTrue();
    if (locked_list.size() == 0) {
        doStopSelf();
    }
    this.isRefreshedList = true;
}

@SuppressLint({ "InlinedApi" })
private void startForegroundWithNotification() {
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
            Calculator_Activity.class), 0);
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    String content = getString(R.string.app_name);
    Builder nb = new Builder(this);
    nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_transparent);
    nb.setContentTitle(title);
    nb.setContentText(content);
    nb.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    nb.setContentIntent(pi);
    nb.setOngoing(true);
    nb.setPriority(0);
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, nb.build());
}

private void startNotification() {
    startForegroundWithNotification();
    if (!this.mShowNotification) {
        HelperService.removeNotification(this);
    }
}

private void doStopSelf() {
    this.mAllowDestroy = true;
    unregisterReceiver(this.mReciever);
    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();
}

private void confirmPattern(String st) {

    Intent pIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            ResetActivity.class);
    pIntent.putExtra("isFromReset", true);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
            12345, pIntent, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY);

    Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN, null,
            getApplicationContext(), LockPatternActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("packName", st);
    intent.putExtra("isStealthMode", this.prefs.getBoolean(
            AlpSettings.Display.METADATA_STEALTH_MODE, false));
    intent.putExtra("isFromLock", true);
    intent.setFlags(DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    intent.addFlags(Cast.MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH);

    intent.putExtra(LockPatternActivity.EXTRA_PENDING_INTENT_FORGOT_PATTERN, pi);

    startActivity(intent);

}

private void removeAppFromLockedList(String packName) {
    locked_list.remove(packName);
}
```

if there is any solution for it then please help me out thanks in advance

Comment: Run the service using Alarm Manager and check there if service is not running or stopped the start it again.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the service when it's stopped i.e. System will call onDestroy() on service which is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

1. set a variable in service class  to check service is running or not.
2. let boolRuningService is a variable

Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardScreen.this, ServiceClass.class);
     PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(DashboardScreen.this, 0, intent, 0);

```
                    if(!ServiceClass.boolRuningService){
                           AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);
                    }
```